# Windows 10 Immersive Search tweak

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-search

Windows has an unofficial feature called "*Immersive Search*," similar to [Spotlight Search](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204014) on macOS, that looks like this:

[image: Immersive Search Screenshot]

It can be enabled with the following Registry Commands, either with `regedit` or by saving the following registry file and running it:

**`ImmersiveSearch.reg`**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search]
"ImmersiveSearch"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Flighting\Override]
"CenterScreenRoundedCornerRadius"=dword:00000009
"ImmersiveSearchFull"=dword:00000001
```

**However** on Build 19041 with multiple monitors, it appears to not work and instead overlaps the search and the menu bar like this:

[image: broken example]

Yes, it's still experimental and not fully supported, but anybody else run into the same issue and figured out what registry settings to update?

**Further Reading**:

- [How to Enable or Disable Floating Immersive Search Bar in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/98610-enable-disable-floating-immersive-search-bar-windows-10-a.html#step6)
- [What Is Win­dows 10 Immer­sive Search and Should You Enable It](https://www.guidingtech.com/windows-10-immersive-search-enable/)
- [How to enable hidden immersive search on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-immersive-search-windows-10/)

Comment: FYI, I have  [Version 10.0.16299.1625] and Win-S summons Immersive Search on my multi-monitor rig AOK.

Comment: @K7AAY, hmm, interesting to know.  The multi-monitor and winver were just the two things I thought could be at play and seems to be happening in [this thread as well](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/98610-enable-disable-floating-immersive-search-bar-windows-10-a.html#post1750683), but I wonder what else could be impacting the search UI?  Thanks for the data point!